# How to count records from Locate function - DELPHI

Tags: delphi

I would like to know if there is any way to count how many records the Locate function have found in Delphi.
Thank you.

Comment: `Locate` finds the first record, if any, which matches the specified value(s), so you would need to iterate over the following records and count them yourself.

Comment: Depending on you underlying problem, there could be a better solution than `locate` . For example a SQL request just to count the record matching a criteria. But you didn't mention the actual underlying problem so this is pure speculation.

Comment: `Locate` finds the first match, so if `Locate` returns `True`, it means that the count of the records that `Locate` found is 1. If you need more than that, then `Locate` won't do it for you. It only returns True (1 found) or False (none found).

Answer (score 1):

To expand @MartinA comment let me point you to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Locate). It states:

> If Locate finds a match, the first record containing the match becomes the current record. Locate returns True if it finds a matching record, False if it does not. If a search fails, the current record does not change.

You can use [Filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) and [RecordCount](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.RecordCount) to count matches.